# How to show a header in index page and another different one in the other pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering

I want to show a header menu in index, but I want the rest of the views to have a different menu.

I thought about using 2 different partials, but with this solution I have to manually render a partial in each view.

```
_index_menu.html.erb and _other_menu.html.erb
```

Is there a better practice?

Thanks!

Comment: This sort of logic is best placed in layout file which is shared across all the pages.  You could create two different layouts or render the header on some condition.  Have a look at `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

Comment: @vee so you mean creating 2 application.html.erb??

Comment: No, not creating 2 application.html.erb.  If you want two layouts then leave application.html.erb and create another.  If you want to do it with single layout add some `if...else` logic for swapping the header partials.

Comment: But that wont work @vee. I have 20 views. 1 should render one type of header, the other 19 should render the other type of header. 

How do I say "If it's the index page, render the first type of header?"